# Can't we manage std::map<string,ofstream>?

Tags: c++11, ofstream

I tried to create for outputting the timing results and call any ofstream from pre-defined string:

```
#include <cstring>                                                                                                                  
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    map<string,ofstream> Map;
    ofstream ofs("test_output");
    string st="test";
    Map[st] = ofs;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error; how can I fix it?

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:11:8: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  Map[s]=ofs;
        ^
In file included from a.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/fstream:744:7: note: declared here
   operator=(const basic_ofstream&) = delete;

       ^
In file included from a.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/fstream:744:7: note: declared here
   operator=(const basic_ofstream&) = delete;
```

Comment: Streams can't be copied, you need to [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an `std::ostream` is not copyable (copy constructor and assignment operator are marked deleted), you have to either construct the ofstream directly in the map (e.g. using [`std::map::emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)) or use move assignment.

## Construct in-place

There are basically two ways, either default-construct stream in the map (pre C++11), or call [`std::map::emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) to supply `ofstream` constructor arguments.

Using default-construction (works even pre C++11):

```
map<string,ofstream> m;

// default-construct stream in map    
ofstream& strm = m["test"];
strm.open("test_output");
strm << "foo";
```

Using emplacement:

```
// 1st parameter is map key, 2nd parameter is ofstream constructor parameter    
auto res = m.emplace("test", "test_output");
auto& strm = res.first->second;
strm << "bar";
```

## Move assignment

We can construct the stream outside of the map first, turn it into an [rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) by calling [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and use [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) to move it into the map:

```
map<string,ofstream> m;    
ofstream strm("test_output");
m["test"] = std::move( strm );
// strm is not "valid" anymore, it has been moved into the map
```

We can even get rid of `std::move()` if we directly create the stream as an [rvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

```
m["test"] = ofstream("test_output");
```

Move assignment is less efficient than the other methods, because first a stream will be default-constructed in the map, just to be replaced by the move-assigned stream then.

[Live demo of all three methods.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4486879ce9d4db0)

**Note:** Sample code omitts any error handling for brevity. State of stream should be checked after opening and after each stream operation.

Comment: Glad to see more general answer here. Thanks!

Comment: @zorutic I added even simpler example of move assignment: `m["test2"] = ofstream("test_output")`.

Answer (score 4):

This comes from the fact that you can't copy an `ostream` you can only move it. You get this error because the copy assignment operator is deleted. Instead the map must take ownership of the stream:

```
Map[st] = std::move(ofs);
```

Now this also means that you will have to be careful when iterating over your map. You must avoid copies and also avoid stealing the ownership from the map.

On a side note, please note that `using namespace std;` is not recommended.

Comment: Moving is not the only solution.

Comment: @zett42 Indeed, an approach with (smart) pointers could be used (and would have the added benefit of handling polymorphism)

Comment: This is not what I was thinking about, see my answer.